# Watson Dialog does not recognize continuation of conversation

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-dialog

When trying to use the Dialog tool to get a feel for how the APIs work, I ran into a problem where a POST to /conversation creates a new conversation, instead of continuing an existing one. I am using the docs found at : http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/dialog/api/v1/

An initial POST returns a conversation and client id, but subsequent requests with those values added, along with an input value, just return information for a new conversation. Are these docs inaccurate?

Here is a screenshot from one of my many attempts at getting this to work. The client and connection IDs are from a previous POST to /conversation

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6osi.jpg

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Worked OK for me:  "Sounds good! Your pizza will be ready in 20 minutes. Do you want to order another?"

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm screwing something up? The conversation and client id's are from an initial POST to the URL.

http://imgur.com/4035dWe

Comment: I left out client id. That caused problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was using the incorrect encoding for the conversation / client ID's and input. Watson expects the form values to be URL encoded. Once I made that change, the problem was resolved.

Thanks to everyone who offered their time and help!

Answer (score 2):

Your first call to Converse you should not specify the conversation ID. Dialog will return a conversation ID with the first response.

You then use that ID going forward to maintain the conversation. It is unclear if you are doing this in the example above.

Comment: Right, I had gotten those conversation and client ID's from a previous call, and what was pictured was the result of the shown call. I managed to figure it out, though! Details in my answer.